# Linq to SQL - Serialization

Tags: linq-to-sql, serialization

How to mark System.Data.Linq.EntitySet and System.Data.Linq.EntityRef fields with with Serializable attribute the LINQ class.

In the Object Relational Designer, changed the Serialization Mode property to Unidirectional.

Still throwing below error:

```
Type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1 [[CIMS.Framework.DataAccess.Models.Assessments_ResponseWorkflow, 
CIMS.Framework.DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of 
the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:
Type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1 
[[CIMS.Framework.DataAccess.Models.Assessments_ResponseWorkflow,  
CIMS.Framework.DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

Any example please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps but you can serialize your LINQ-to-SQL generated classes by having manually created partial classes, that correspond to the LINQ-to-SQL partial classes, inherit a base entity which is flagged as serialized. For example:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseEntity 
{
    // Code...
}

public partial class Customer : BaseEntity
{
   // Code...
}
```

This ensures that a LINQ-to-SQL class like **Customer**, and any other partial classes that inherit BaseEntity, are serialized.